# React and React-Snap on Heroku – exceeded slug size

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-snap

#### App structure

I've got an app that's being deployed to Heroku. The folder structure looks like this:

```
- package.json // package.json for my backend.
- node_modules // My Express API node modules
- index.js // My Express API code
- client
-- package.json // package.json for my React-based frontend
-- ... folders from create-react-app
```

My backend `package.json` takes care of building the `create-react-app` frontend, by performing `build` command:

```
"build": "cd ./client && npm install && npm run build"
```

I've modified my frontend `package.json` as stated in this [github issue comment](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack/issues/13#issuecomment-388307071).
Everything seems to run fine, but then **Heroku complains about exceeding maximum slug size (500mb)**.

#### My question

Can I somehow improve this configuration so the slug size stays under the limit? Seems like installing the puppeteer and chrome buildpacks takes a lot of slug space – can this be somehow minimized?

Comment: Did you commit `node_modules`?

Comment: @coreyward – I have them in my `.gitignore`. Maybe I should also put them in `.slugignore` – I will try this

Comment: Assuming you don't have your dev dependencies installed as primary dependencies you should be okay there then. I know there's been a lot of chatter about various Node-targeted buildpacks being too bloated. Heroku is kind of a bad fit for Node apps, alas.

Comment: I used to split my backend and frontend into two separate apps but decided to go for one this time. Adding the `node_modules` to `.slugignore` did not help unfortunately.